# Delete Items From Listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

Ok, I'm having trouble looping through a listbox of items and delete them based on the filesystemwatcher.

Users enter a numeric value into a textbox and I'm adding them to the listbox.

```
Listbox1.Items.Add(Textbox1.Text)
```

Here how I was currently looping through the listbox items and triggering a msgbox for testing purposes.

```
Public Sub CheckCreatedPDFs()
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim Watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()
        Watcher.Path = "C:\Temp\"
        Watcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.Attributes)
        Watcher.Filter = ListBox1.Items(i) + ".pdf"

        AddHandler Watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged

        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    ' Specify what is done when a file is created.
    MsgBox("SPACE RESERVED FOR REMOVING LISTBOX ITEMS")
End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to remove those items? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Store the return of `ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(e.Name)`. If it's greater than -1, use `ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(SavedIndex)`. I don't use `VB.Net`, so I can't provide the exact code.

In C#, it would be something like this:

```
private void OnChanged(object Sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    var Idx = listbox1.Items.IndexOf(e.Name);
    if (Idx > -1) 
    {
      listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(Idx);
    }
}
```